# How do I update the attribute value when making an external change?

Tags: c++, class, stack

I have three classes A, B and C. (There is an overload of the output stream, but for example I did not write it). Their structure is shown below.

After adding an instance of class B to the stack of class A, there is a need to add data to the stack of class B. But the data in the class A instance does not change at the same time, and I need the changes to be.I will give an example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
class C{
public:
    int Age;
    C(int Age_o) {
        Age= Age_o;
    }
    void set_Age(int Age_o){Age= Age_o;}
    template <class T> friend T& operator<<(T& stream, C obj) {
        stream << obj.Age << endl;
        return stream;
    }
};
class B{
public:
    int Size;
    stack <C> CStack;
    B(int Size_o) {
        Size= Size_o;
    }
    void set_Size(int Size_o){Size= Size_o;}
    void set_CStack(C obj){CStack.push(obj);}
    template <class T> friend T& operator<<(T& stream, B obj) {
        stream << obj.Size << endl;
        while(!obj.CStack.empty()){
              stream << obj.CStack.top()<<endl;
              obj.CStack.pop();
            }
        return stream;
    }
};
class A{
public:
    string Name;
    stack <B> BStack;
    A(string Name_o) {
        Name = Name_o;
    }
    void set_Name(string Name_o){Name = Name_o;}
    void set_BStack(B obj){BStack.push(obj);}
    template <class T> friend T& operator<<(T& stream, A obj) {
        stream << obj.Name << endl;
        while(!obj.BStack.empty()){
              stream << obj.BStack.top()<<endl;
              obj.BStack.pop();
            }
        return stream;
    }
};
int main()
{
    C c1(1);
    B b1(1);
    b1.set_CStack(c1);
    A a1("Text");
    a1.set_BStack(b1);
    C c2(2);
    b1.set_CStack(c2);
    cout << a1;
    return 0;
}
```

Will output:

```
"Text"
      1
         1
```

Necessary:

```
"Text"
      1
         1
         2
```

At the moment, I was able to come up with adding an ID for an instance of class B and tracking it by going through the stack elements.

Comment: Does this code even compile? Class `B` hasn't been declared yet when the `A::BStack` and `A::set_BStack()` members are declared. Class `C` hasn't been declared yet when the `B::CStack` and `B::set_CStack()` members are declared.

Comment: user17732522 is right, there is no `d1` declaration and you need to provide an MRE. But, you also don't do anything with `d1` AFAICT. It looks like you need something like `a1.BStack.set_CStack(c2)`.

Comment: I have removed all inaccuracies and conventions, the code is now definitely working.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , Yes, you're right. Since in my program the classes are located in separate files, transferring to the example I did not take into account their sequence.

Comment: `a1.set_BStack(b1);` adds a copy of `b1` to `a1`s stack. Both because `b1` is passed by value, and ALSO because `std::stack::push()` explicitly places a copy on the stack.   Upshot is that `b1.set_CStack(c2)` affects `b1`, not the copy of it held by `a1`.  What you need is for `A` to provide a member function that returns a reference to an object from its stack (arguments of that member function are used to select which object to return) which will be used in a manner akin to `a1.pickB(<args>).set_CStack(c2)`

Comment: @Peter , That is, I still need to keep track of which element of the stack I want to add a new element to?(That is, set some ID for each instance of class "B" and search for it).

Comment: Yeah.  If you want to modify an object that is being managed by an instance of `A`, then the class `A` needs to provide facilities which allow that to happen.    One way is for `A` to provide a means to obtain a reference to an object (and, if there are multiple objects managed by an `A`, you need to provide information so the `A` can decide which one).  Another way is for `A` to provide helper functions that indirectly modify contained objects (in which case, the caller doesn't need access to the objects themselves).

Answer (score 1):

`void set_BStack(B obj)` accepts `B` by value, i.e.: a copy of `B`. Similarly `stack <B> BStack` stores a copy of `B`.

You'll either want to use pointers or references there if you want them to be mutable once stored.

Comment: I assumed so, but I didn't get an option in which I would be able to put references to instances of class "B" on the stack in class "A". Could you show your version of this implementation?